# Maintain Backbone Collection References

Tags: backbone.js, collections, marionette

I have been running into the problem of stale collection references. So, I have the following model:

```
ProcessModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.set('steps', new StepsCollection());
    }
    ...
});
```

When the ProcessModel is fetched from the server, the StepsCollection is returned as well. Previously, I had the following parse method:

```
parse: function(response) {
    ...
    response.steps = new StepsCollection(response.steps, {parse: true});
}
```

...however, this was creating a brand new collection object, rather than reusing the existing one. This was causing a view which was bound to the previous "steps" collection to become stale.

I've tried the following:

```
response.steps = this.get('steps').reset(response.steps);
```

But I get a long stacktrace in Object.Marionette.bindEntityEvents. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This will create single collection and then we'll reset same collection instance with new data-set inside parse method.

```
    ProcessModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.myCollection = new StepsCollection();
            this.set('steps', this.myCollection);
            ...
        },
        parse: function(response) {

            this.myCollection.reset(response.steps);
            this.set('steps', this.myCollection);
            ...
        }

   });
```

Comment: I forgot I had posted this :-)

Comment: This is basically what I ended doing, albeit with some guards in initialize(...) and parse(...) to handle the situation where the model is created on the clientside and the situation where the model comes directly from the server.

Comment: Oh, and the weird error I got were caused by the parsing of sub-elements in the Step model